# Automatic vs dynamic memory allocation: what to consider?

Tags: c, memory-management, allocation

In C, we can allocate memory [automatically](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_variable) or [dynamically](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_dynamic_memory_allocation):

```
size_t foo = 128;
char str1[64];            // Automatic
char str2[foo]            // Automatic (variable-length, C99)
char *str3 = malloc(64);  // Dynamic
char *str4 = malloc(foo); // Dynamic
```

With automatic allocation, variables have a limited scope and the memory is usually allocated on the stack, whereas dynamic allocation uses the heap.

Let's stick with strings and say a function is supposed to return a string that it somehow creates. There seem to be two common practices, both can be seen with standard library functions:

1. Take a buffer and a size, then write into the provided buffer
2. Allocate a buffer with `malloc()` and return the pointer to it

The first has the advantage that we don't need to remember to `free()` the memory. On the other hand, we need to hand in two additional arguments and somehow need to determine from the outside what size the buffer should have:

```
char str1[128];              // Let's hope this is large enough!
fill_my_buffer(str1, 128);   // Might need more than 128, who knows

char *str2 = return_a_ptr(); // Just give me a pointer
size_t len = strlen(str2);   // Ah, so that's what we got!
```

What (other) considerations should be taken into account when choosing between automatic or dynamic memory allocation in C?

---

The question was closed as opinion-based, but I'm convinced it should be possible to compile a comprehensive list of *objective* pros and cons for either approach, which would then allow making informed decision on a case-by-case basis.

Comment: It feels like a candidate for migration to https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic but nobody is ever quite sure what that site is for anymore (and flagging for migration is horribly broken-by-design anyway).

Comment: To get a clear picture, you need to fully understand the differences between automatic and dynamic allocation, and the advantages and disadvantages of both over one another. Then you wont have to worry about it at all. It will feel natural when it is better to use one of the two approaches.

Comment: @machine_1 That sound like the right way to go about it. I've changed my question using some of your words, hoping that this makes it less opinion based. Maybe you want to try your hand at an answer yourself? I'm very interested in your insights.

Comment: This is frustrating. I reworded the question as best as I can, I asked for help. From what I can tell, I think the question is worthwhile. I also think it can be answered in a rather objective way. Yet, I (and everyone else who is interested) do not get a chance at any further answers because it got closed as opinion based without any hints as to how I could improve it.

Comment: I suggest you stick to "automatic allocation", since when using the "dynamic allocation" in your example (even after warning about possibly forgetting to `free()` it) you forgot to `free()` it.

Comment: @pmg that was not forgetting, but omitting for briefness, like the rest of the "program".

Answer (score 3):

One rule of thumb is that you should avoid "large" allocations on the stack. A page (4096 bytes) or two is fine, but anything larger should be heap-allocated.

Changing the stack pointer too much will kill your cache performance, and cache is king.

Also, you might overflow the stack and *miss* the guard page, although this is mostly only a problem with threads which necessarily have limited-size stacks, or else on otherwise constrained systems which can't have automatic main-thread stack growth.

---

Other than that, the main question is semantics: does this (small) object "belong" to this stack frame, or does it need to live for a different period of time (longer or shorter).

The need to call `free` should not be a concern at all, there are all *sorts* of functions that always must be called in pairs (which is the main problem that C++ tried to address, and also GNU's `__attribute__((cleanup))` extension) and you should develop the discipline of always knowing to do it.

Notably, every function that *takes* a pointer should have a concept of "who is in charge of this ownership"? Common ownership models include: borrowed (owned by some higher stack frame), uniquely-owned, and shared (often refcounted) ownership, although there can be dozens of subtle variants (though not all in the same program).

Answer (score 1):

It's basically a judgement call — can the calling code know how big a buffer is likely to be?

- If so, it is probably better that it provides the buffer and the called code must ensure it doesn't overflow it (which in turn means that the interface must specify the size of the buffer provided).
- If not, then the called code should allocate and return the memory.

The complication with the caller-provided buffer is "what to do when the provided space isn't big enough".  The complications with the caller-provided buffer are ensuring it is freed appropriately and deciding what to do if memory allocation fails.

Comment: Not sure why someone downvoted you, this answer is definitely helpful to me. Thank you.